# Access a Docker Container via Alias behind a reverse proxy from another container

Tags: docker, gitlab, reverse-proxy, alias, cypress

I'm trying to use ZAP-Docker as a yml file service, inside a Docker Container where Cypress is contained (End-to-End test execution).
I'm using ZAP as a reverse proxy, the idea would be to divert traffic from Cypress to ZAP. As you can imagine, however, I can't use the ip address of the zap container. So I'm trying a solution using aliases.

This is a piece of the yml file:

```
services:
  - name: owasp/zap2docker-stable:latest
    alias: zap
    ports:
        - "8092:8092"
    entrypoint: ["zap.sh"]
    command: ["-daemon", "-port", "8092", "-host", "0.0.0.0", "-config", "api.disablekey=true", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.name=.*", "-config", "api.addrs.addr.regex=true"]
```

This is the command I use to divert traffic to the ZAP container (using its alias)

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://zap:8092 npx cypress run
```

Cypress documentation [Here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/proxy-configuration.html#Set-a-proxy-on-Linux-or-macOS)

Unfortunately I get this error from Cypress by executing the test:

```
Cypress could not verify that this server is running:

  > https://app.cloud

We are verifying this server because it has been configured as your `baseUrl`.

Cypress automatically waits until your server is accessible before running tests.
```